# Building clang from source code on Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, atl, llvm-clang, ninja

Its been a While that I tried to build clang from source code.

I tried with 2 platforms 
  a> Ubuntu
  b> Windows

I am following the link http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html

> > Ubuntu

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -GNinja -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ /path/to/source/llvm
```

After this in build directory ninja.build files generated along with some more folder

`$ ninja` after this command `inside build directory bin` folder can be seen and it contains all the clang executables `clang,clang++,clang-check and many more`.

> > Windows

I tried every option that is available to build clang from source
I am trying on developer command prompt and also I am having `VS Express edition`

```
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ path-to-llvm
```

It throws error

```
Host compiler appears to require libatomic,but cannot find it.
```

So I tried in the another way by making DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and DCMAKE_C_COMPILER as clang-cl.exe

```
> cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl.exe path-to-llvm
```

It didnt show any error at first but later while building

```
atlbase.h file not found
```

Why it is that much difficult to build clang from source on windows.?

Is this the correct procedure that I am doing?

Kindly help with any solution.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am running into the same problem

Comment: On Windows you really should install Visual Studio Community edition (such as VS2019 Community) and then use `-G "Visual Studio 16 2019"` as generator. I doubt if Express edition has all necessary bits. I am following http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html "Using Visual Studio" section and it seems to work.